# How do I load local directory into path in urls.py

Tags: python, django, path, django-urls

I saved my homepage.html file in my laptop [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PBzP.jpg) D:\Python\WebDjango\BaseCoffeehouse\coffeehouse\templates.

Then in urls.py (open in VSCode), I added the path as below :

```
path('D:/Python/WebDjango/BaseCoffeehouse/coffeehouse/templates', 
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'), name='homepage'),
```

When I run the server (python manage.py runserver), I got an error message "Page not found 404" in the default port 8000.

So, how should I do it to open my homepage.html file?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of notes:
1.)
It looks like that you placed your `templates` folder inside the root app's dir. Make sure the `templates` folder is at the same hierarchy than manage.py to make the default Django template routing work:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

2.)
In your urls.py file the path instance shouldn't "point" to your html file but rather to the web `url`. So try that

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', YourView.as_view(), name='home'),
],
```

which would return the template if you visit localhost/127.0.0.1 for example. Also see the [official docs](https://urlpatterns%20=%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20path(%27%27,%20HomePageView.as_view(),%20name=%27home%27),%20%5D) for `TemplateView`.

Comment: Great, it works. I moved my templates folder to the root directory, add "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / 'templates'] to settings.py and  path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'homepage.html'), name='homepage'), to urls.py.  Thanks.